# How can I display a JavaScript function into the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a programmer student and I am having a problem with my Java Script code :(

I'm supposed to make a madlib game, I have everything in it except that I can't figure it out how to show the output of the story and the words entered by the user onto the same window.

I was told to use arrays and loops, but it just seems overly and unnecessarily complicated to me (maybe I'm wrong though).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Madlib Game!</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Fill in the blanks and then press "View story"</p>
<form>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5"><tr><td>

Adjective:
<input type="text" name="input1" size="15"><tr><td>


Adjective:
<input type="text" name="input2" size="15"><tr><td>


Plural Noun:
<input type="text" name="input3" size="15"><tr><td>


Verb (ending in 'ing'):
<input type="text" name="input4" size="15"><tr><td>


Edible Object:
<input type="text" name="input5" size="15"><tr><td>


Monster:
<input type="text" name="input6" size="15"><tr><td>


Adjective:
<input type="text" name="input7" size="15"><tr><td>


Monster (again):
<input type="text" name="input8" size="15"><tr><td>


Verb (ending in 'ing'):
<input type="text" name="input9" size="15">
</table>

<input type="button" value="View Story" onclick="makeStory()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my JavaScript code...

```
function makeStory()
{ 
  text = ("Rain was still lashing the windows, which were now " +input1.value+"but inside all looked bright and cheerful. ");
  text += ("The firelight glowed over the countless " + input2.value + input3.value + "where people sat, talking, doing homework or, ");
  text += ("in the case of Fred and George Weasley, trying to find out what would  happen if you fed a " +input4.value+ "to a " +input5.value);
  text += (". Fred had 'rescued' the "+input6.value+", fire-dwelling "+input7.value+"from a Care of Magical Creatures class and it was now ");
  text += (+input8+ " gently on a table surrounded by a knot of curious people.");
        document.write(text);
}
```

Oh god I hope I made those block of codes right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could use arrays and loops. You had a lot of issues in your html - you were missing the `<tbody>` and none of your table rows `<tr>` and cells `<td>` were closed. Don't use inline javascript (`onclick` in your html). Write that in javascript where it belongs - see my example below. [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/uwEnIje/2/edit)

```
var pieces = [
  "Rain was still lashing the windows, which were now ",
  " ,but inside all looked bright and cheerful. ",
  "The firelight glowed over the countless ",
  "where people sat, talking, doing homework or, ",
  "in the case of Fred and George Weasley, trying to find out what would  happen if you fed a ",
  "to a ",
  ". Fred had 'rescued' the ",
  ", fire-dwelling ",
  "from a Care of Magical Creatures class and it was now ",
  " gently on a table surrounded by a knot of curious people."
];

function makeStory() {
  var result = '';
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

  for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i) {
    result+= pieces[i]+inputs[i].value;
  }
  result+= pieces[inputs.length];

  var storyElem = document.getElementById('story');
  storyElem.textContent = result;

  var inputSection = document.getElementById('input-section');
  inputSection.style.display = 'none';
}

var button = document.getElementById('make-story');
button.addEventListener('click', makeStory);
```

html:

```
<p id="story"></p>

<div id="input-section">
<p>Fill in the blanks and then press "View story"</p>
<form>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Adjective:
      <input type="text" name="input1" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Adjective:
      <input type="text" name="input2" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Plural Noun:
      <input type="text" name="input3" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Verb (ending in 'ing'):
      <input type="text" name="input4" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Edible Object:
      <input type="text" name="input5" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Monster:
      <input type="text" name="input6" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Adjective:
      <input type="text" name="input7" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Monster (again):
      <input type="text" name="input8" size="15">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Verb (ending in 'ing'):
      <input type="text" name="input9" size="15">
    <td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</form>
<button id="make-story">View Story</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked fine! And I actually understood how the array worked since it was my biggest issue, but it seemed clear in this example.

Thank you so much! It was a big help.